# Updating aws apigateway binaryMediaTypes with javascript SDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway

If I want to configure the binaryMediaTypes  [ 'image/jpg', 'text/html' ] for an API through nodejs. What is the right API to use? It looks like the below is not working.

```
const config = JSON.stringify({
            "swagger": "2.0",
            "info": {
                "title": this.apiName
            },
            "x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types": [ 'image/jpg', 'text/html' ]
        });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var params = {
                restApiId: apiId, /* required */
                mode: 'merge',
                body: config
            };
            this.apiGatewaySDK.putRestApi(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve('binary set successfully');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

we end up using updateRestApi(). Pls note the patchOpertions part, it is very unintuitive (sth aws sdk could improve? )

```
        let patchOperationsArray = [];
        patchOperationsArray.push(
            {
                op: 'add',
                path: '/binaryMediaTypes/'+ e.replace("/", "~1")
            }
        );

        const params = {
            restApiId: apiId, /* required */
            patchOperations:patchOperationsArray
        };
        this.apiGatewaySDK.updateRestApi(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                this.serverless.cli.log('API Gateway Configuring: Binary support are set correctly');
                resolve('binary set successfully');
            }
        });
```